# File System Watcher in C# gets fired only once

Tags: c#, .net

I am kicking off a File System Watcher in a system tray application. It monitor's a text file in a local folder. But the FS_changed event is fired only once after starting the application.

```
 FileSystemWatcher fWatch = new FileSystemWatcher();
 fWatch.BeginInit();     
 fWatch.Path = Path.GetTempPath();
 fWatch.Filter = "File1.txt";                       
 fWatch.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(fWatch_Changed);
 fWatch.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
 fWatch.EndInit();
```

I am not handling the Created/Deleted, kind of events. But I tried those as well(just to check) and they are not being called at all although that local file is being deleted and created during this process.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Have you set the NotifyFilter property to capture the appropriate events?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters.aspx

Comment: Simply by adding the Eventhandler's I should be able to catch the File Changing events or Creation/Deletion kind of event. NotifyFilters are for added filtering requirements which was not needed in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably getting garbage collected. Are you keeping a reference to that object?

Comment: IMHO the event subscription should keep it in memory

Comment: Unless the object that holds the event handler (which may be one and the same) is eligible for GC as well.

Comment: @alexm: No, it's not really subjective :).  An event handler maintains an active reference to the *subscriber*, preventing *it* from being GC'd, not the other way around.  That would be an awful design and would require unsubscribing to every event you ever subscribe to else be subjected to memory issues.  This is probably the right answer.

Comment: I was expecting the Event handlers to hold on to the reference. By maintaining a reference to this object, it works fine now. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the instance of fWatch is not being disposed? Is it part of a method that keeps listening all the time otherwise you might be getting the event only while the instance lives. Can you please put the code you are using to keep the watcher alive so we can help you more in detail.

Answer (score 0):

as one of the overloads coud you pass the path that you're wanting to watch into the constructor of that object

```
 FileSystemWatcher fWatch = new FileSystemWatcher(Path.GetTempPath());
```

for example..?